# Who should ensure that the project with one product uses 1 PO and 1 Product Backlog?

Tags: scrum, agile-project-management

Management are involved. They want to split the product into multiple streams but it's still one product.
Management have introduced multiple Product Owners and given then a stream each.

The Scrum Masters are recommending 1 product = 1 owner = 1 backlog. Management disagree.

Everyone is pulling their hair out with dependencies, it's a mess.

Who should take action and what?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the project this is possible. I would recommend looking into LeSS Huge we use this system for larger projects. You keep one Product Backlog, one definition of done, one product & one main PO. You just add extra areas or "sub" projects that are directed from their own areaPO that takes from the main backlog. The main PO just divides it more into manageable chunks and makes sure that parallel parts don't have to wait on other parts of the project to finish